# Drupal 6 Availability of View Basic Settings Variables

Tags: drupal-6, view

I've been doing some basic view theming with Drupal 6, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to access certain variables. Here is my setup:

- I have one view with several block displays.
- I three templates I'm using to override the default:

  - views-view-unformatted-my-list-blocks.tpl.php (styles template)
  - views-view-my-list-blocks.tpl.php (rows template)
  - views-view-fields-my-list-blocks-block-1.tpl.php (an example display template)

Now, if I just copy the default code into the templates, everything seems to display as it should. But I noticed that in my styles template, the title variable is there, but nothing comes out. Even when I set my display title in basic settings, nothing shows. I would also like to access my CSS class variable from the basic settings, but I'm not sure what variable to use for that either.

Can anyone shed some light on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on doing this

http://www.expresstut.com/content/themeing-views-drupal-6
http://www.expresstut.com/content/themeing-views-drupal-6-part-2